# Apache Shiro - "Reverse" Implies

Tags: java, permissions, shiro

### Situation

Assume you have the following permissions:
`printer:my-printer:print`
`printer:my-printer-2:print`

No I want to know if a user has the `print` permission on **at least one** printer, without knowing the list of printers.

### Trials

At first I tried to check for `*:*:print`, but after reading the documentation it is clear that this will check if the user has the permission to print on **all** printers.

According to the documentation it only works the other way round as permissions are implied, so `printer:my-printer:*` will imply `printer:my-printer:print`.

Unfortunately I have not found a way to check for "**at least one**".
Is there something like `printer:+:print` (referring to regex here)?

---

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Subject.isPermitted()`

`boolean[] isPermitted(List<Permission> permissions);`

Though, typically you don't need to do this. You would assign a user `printer:*:print` and your application would check to see if they could `print` on a specific printer using the permission: `printer:my-printer:print`.  I know this is an overly general answer, maybe you can provide a more explanation of your use case, and we could provide other ideas/suggestions to model your permissions?